# Where do winning strategies occur for Player II in the Determinacy of Computable Open Games relative to a parameter?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, descriptive-set-theory, infinite-games

Moschovakis goes over various theorems proving the Determinacy of closed/open games, and I am reading  into various papers regarding the characterization of ordinals where winning strategies for the players are definable over. My question is as follows:

Let $\gamma$ denote the least ordinal such that $\omega_{\gamma}^{CK} = \gamma.$ In other words, it is $\kappa$ as in Moschovakis' Descriptive Set Theory on page 221, where this inductive definition of $W$ closes off. There are various other characterizations of this ordinal, like it being the first $\Pi_1^{1}$ gap-reflecting ordinal, or the least non-Gandy ordinal, etc, but these are not important.  Consider a computable open game relative to a parameter which is definable over $L_{\gamma}$. Where must the strategies for the open player show up?

My attempt? It seems pretty obvious that they will show up by $L_{\gamma^{+}}$, where $\gamma^{+}$  denotes the next admissible ordinal after $\gamma.$ But is this upper bound sharp? Will the winning strategies show up much before then?

Comment: What is "a parameter which is simply definable over $L_\gamma$"? Is that an $x\subseteq\omega$ which is parameter-freely first-order definable over $L_\gamma$? (The "simply" is throwing me off.)

Comment: Apologies. Will take this word out. I meant it colloquially. It's just definable over $L_{\gamma}$. @NoahSchweber

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand something in this post, which is that if $\gamma$ is the least ordinal such that $\gamma=\omega_\gamma^{CK}$, then $\gamma$ is smaller than the least non-Gandy ordinal according to Madore's [A Zoo of Ordinals](http://www.madore.org/~david/math/ordinal-zoo.pdf).